# count of individual column with group by on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns account_number and customer_id. A single customer can have multiple account but a single account can't have multiple customer.

I have dumped a file containing account_num and its corresponding customer_id to db through `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. Now I am trying to validate through query does any account which has come multiple times in a file has same customer_id or different customer_id in two different rows.

**REQUIREMENT : i want to return those accounts which has come multiple times but having diferent customer ids**

I tried with group by , but didn't get desired result.
This is my query which is not giving the desired result

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUM,UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID,COUNT(UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID) 
FROM LINKAGE_FILE   
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUM, UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID 
HAVING COUNT(ACCOUNT_NUM) > 1 AND COUNT(UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID) = 1;
```

Hope I am clear.

Comment: Are you saying an account can appear with the same customer multiple times?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes can come multiple times with same customer , also with different customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get the count of unique customer ids using `COUNT(DISTINCT..)` for every `account_num` and filter out those cases where count is more than 1, inside the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  ACCOUNT_NUM, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID) AS unique_customer_count 
FROM LINKAGE_FILE 
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUM
HAVING unique_customer_count > 1
```

Comment: i want to return those accounts which has come multiple times but having diferent customer ids

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT lf.*
FROM LINKAGE_FILE lf
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LINKAGE_FILE lf1 WHERE lf1.ACCOUNT_NUM = lf.ACCOUNT_NUM AND lf1.UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID <> lf.UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

However, you can also aggregation with your query :

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUM, COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID) 
FROM LINKAGE_FILE   
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUM
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID) > 1;
```

By this, you can get only `ACCOUNT_NUM`s which have two or more `CUSTOMER_ID`s.

Comment: I need those account only but this query is continuously running and not giving output.

Comment: i want to return those accounts which has come multiple times but having diferent customer ids

Comment: the first query is running in background but not giving output where as second one works fine but it gives only the count of account number

Comment: @MuddassirRahman. . .That is what this does & for first query you would have index on (`ACCOUNT_NUM` & `UNIQUE_CUSTOMER_ID`).

Comment: yeah it gives ACCOUNT_NUM which has more than 1 customer_id . but I want those account_num which has more than 1 customer_id also and those customer_ids are not same

Answer (score 0):

Drop the customer check into a join query like so

```
DROP TABLE if exists t;
create table t(accountid int,cid int);
insert into t values
(1,1),(1,2).(1,1),(2,3),(3,4),(3,4);

    select distinct t.accountid,t.cid 
from t
join
(
select accountid,count(distinct cid) cids
from t
group by accountid having cids > 1 
) s on s.accountid = t.accountid;

+-----------+------+
| accountid | cid  |
+-----------+------+
|         1 |    1 |
|         1 |    2 |
+-----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```